# How to limit only issue fungible token once with a specific account by Corda Token SDK

Tags: corda

Corda Token SDK https://github.com/corda/token-sdk.
By default, the fungible token can be issued many times, to many accounts.
I do not know to limit that fungible token is issued once and sent to a specific account 
(after that token will not be issued any more)
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement that, you'd have to do the following:

1. Create your own `EvolvableTokenType`.
2. Your evolvable token type will have 2 custom attributes (that can be changed over time, thus why we chose evolvable over fixed token type):

   - `issued` of type `boolean`
   - `issueAccount` of type `AbstractParty`
3. Create a contract that validates your evolvable token type (it should extend `EvolvableTokenContract`):

   - Implement `additionalCreateChecks`: You can keep it empty.
   - Implement `additionalUpdateChecks`: Here you can validate that you can only update the value of `issued` to `true`, you cannot update it to `false` (this will allow issuing more of your token type which we don't want).
4. Create a flow that creates your evolvable token type, it sets the `issueAccount` to the value that you pass as input parameter and sets `issued` to `false`.
5. Now you can create your evolvable token token type and use it to issue tokens of that type.
6. Create a flow that issues tokens of your token type:

   - It will fetch the latest version of your evolvable token type.
   - If the value of `issued` is `true`, throw a `FlowException` that this token has already been issued and you cannot issue it again.
   - Use the returned state to get the `issueAccount` value.
   - Call the `IssueToken` flow to issue your token type to `issueAccount`.  Of course you need to generate a new key for the account using `RequestKeyForAccount` and wrap the returned `PublicKey` in an instance of `AnonymousParty`.
   - Now the most important part (**your requirement**): Call `UpdateEvolvableToken` flow to update your evolvable token type and set `issued` to `true`. This way if someone calls your issue tokens flow again, it will throw an exception because your token type has been `issued`.

The Kotlin template (`token` branch) has a high level example of `EvolvableTokenType`:

1. Type: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/token-template/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/template/states/ExampleEvolvableTokenType.kt
2. Contract: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/token-template/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/template/ExampleEvolvableTokenTypeContract.kt
3. Flow (it has 2 flows, create token type and issue it): https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/blob/token-template/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/template/flows/ExampleFlowWithEvolvableToken.kt

Also the **Tokens SDK** has an example that uses `EvolvableTokenType` where the `House` token has an attribute that can change (`valuation`):
https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/docs/DvPTutorial.md#define-your-states-and-contracts

Comment: can someone make their own flow that issue my token? (that flow does not check issued or not)

Comment: They can, but the `FungibleToken` and `NonFungibleToken` classes have an attribute called `issuer` which will be set to the value of the party that initiated the `IssueTokens` sub-flow. So when someone creates a flow and use your token type to issue tokens; their token will be different from the token that you issue. In Corda 2 tokens are considered different if the `issuer` is different, even though if the token identifier and fraction digits are the same. Think of it this way, if you create a flow that issues USD's it's not going to be accepted like the USD issued by the US treasury.

Comment: Also the evolvable token type has an attribute called `maintainers` which is the list of parties that maintain this token type. Inside `additionalUpdateChecks` in the contract of the toke type you can add checks that the required signers match the list of `maintainers` (which is your party). This way you can lock down that only you can update the token type (i.e. only you can update `issued` from `false` to `true`).

Comment: So you need to add various checks, so when you query your vault to get your tokens; always add a query criteria that the `issuer` is you. This way if someone else created a flow to use your token type; their token is useless in your CorDapp.

Comment: Adel Rustum, thank you, how to check issuer is your account, not by party?

Comment: ```val issuerCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(builder {
        PersistentFungibleToken::issuer.equal(replace-with-your-party)
    })```

Comment: You can use the above criteria when you query the vault.

Comment: `QueryUtilities.kt` from the `Tokens SDK` has lots of useful functions; check it out.

Comment: Adel Rustum, thank you, I marked this question as answered. I just want to ask some extra info :)